# Gives this error when importing utils.sql what could be the problem?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

This error is displayed in the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from utils.sql import ManagerDB
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.sql'
```

Comment: Tried to use pip install utils.sql gives this                                                                                               
ERROR: could not find a version that meets the requirement of utils.sql (from versions: none)
ERROR: The corresponding distribution for utils.sql was not found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

check your project if "utils" is your own python package, name "utils" is too generic,unlikely is a PYPI package which you install by pip